# Поиск первого подходящего элемента

Tags: python, lxml

Как производить поиск только первого происходящего элемента? При нахождении прекращать поиск.

Например:

```
name = item.cssselect('span.title')
```

Ищет span'ы c классом title.

Если мы точно знаем, что в дереве только 1 элемент, зачем нам продолжать поиск, после нахождения элемента, ведь на это тратиться время.

На подобии команды find в Beautiful Soup 4, который ищет только первый подходящий элемент

Поиск можно осуществлять как xpath, так и cssselect.

Comment: это практическая проблема? Вы померили производительность и ваш profiler говорит, что cssselect() является узким местом в вашем приложении? Попробуйте сравнить производительность с `etree.XPath(f'({xpath_expr})[1]')(item)` где `xpath_expr = cssselect.HTMLTranslator().css_to_xpath(css_selector)`¶ Если документ большой, то можно по частям с ним работать, [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26435241/4279).

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать псевдокласс `:first-child` в cssselect.

Comment: Не совсем понял. Как например для такой строчки применить? table_language = html.cssselect('table.game_language_options')[0]

Comment: Первая любая таблица: `cssselect('table:first-child')`, первая таблица с классом `.game_language_options`: `cssselect('table.game_language_options:first-child')` [Примеры на w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#first-child-pseudo)

Comment: это не только "первый подходящий элемент" возвращает. Попробуйте: `[el.text for el in lxml.cssselect.CSSSelector('div.C:first-child')(doc)]`, где `doc = lxml.etree.fromstring('<root><div class="C">a<div class="C">b</div></div></root>')`